# Buscar por fecha en MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

tengo una coleccion llamada usuarios y dentro de esta tengo un arreglo de objetos llamado noticias y necesito hacer consultas por fecha
y te

```
_id:1
nombre: "Jorge Hernandez"
nuck: "ADES"
twitter:"ades@twitter.com"
descripcion:"nice"
nivel: 57
ciudad: "palmira"
telefono: Object
  fijo: "3128239"
  movil: "312748570"
noticias: Array
  0:Object
  titulo: "El principito"
  cuerpo: "imformacion importante aqui"
  fecha: 2018-08-16 19:00:00.000
  tags: Array
    0 : Object
    a : "aaa"
    b : "bbb"
    c : "ccc"
  comentarios : Array
    0 : Object
    comentario : "es muy malo"
    momento : "ahora"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes ir accediendo elemento por elemento hasta llegar a la fecha y luego usar la funcion `ISODate()`

```
{db.usuario.noticias.fecha:ISODate("2018-08-16 19:00:00.000")}
```

espero te sirva... XD

Comment: Funcionando...
muchas gracias.