# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que me regrese una respuesta MongoDB en campo de búsqueda por fecha?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Al realizar una petición regresa un objeto vacío y por mas que lo intento no doy con ello

```
examenServices.getByDate = async (req, res, next) => {
   try {
      //Guardando el rango de fechas
      const fechaInicial = req.body.fecha_inicial;
      const fechaFinal = req.body.fecha_final;
      console.log(fechaInicial);
      const reg = await ExamenChanchamire.find(
         {
            createdAt: {
               $gte: fechaInicial,
               $lt: fechaFinal
            }
         });

      if (!reg) {
         res.status(404).send({
            message: 'El registro no existe'
         });
      } else {
         res.status(200).json({ reg });
      }
   } catch (e) {
      res.status(500).send({
         message: 'Ocurrio un error'
      });
      next(e);
   }
};
```

Objeto que envio desde el frontend

```
{
   "fecha_inicial": "2023-08-23 20:48:43.062Z",
   "fecha_final": "2023-08-23 18:48:43.062Z"
}
```

Esta es la respuesta que me trae como se ve esta totalmente sin nada pero me dice que >tiene un status 200 no entiendo que sucede

```
{
   "reg": []
}
```

Comment: Tal vez te pueda ayudar: [Buscar por fecha en MongoDB](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/189720/buscar-por-fecha-en-mongodb)

Comment: `if([])` es true, pues un array (aun vacío) es un objeto, ergo, es `truthy`. Para evitar eso tendrás que comprobar si reg es un array que su longitud sea mayor a 0. Personalmente prefiero invertir esa lógica y hacer el if así: `if (reg?.length)` puesto que te permite cubrir todas las posibilidades de manera muy simple, si reg no existe o si su longitud es 0 no entrará al if, en caso contrario, si. Siempre que reg sea un array claro.

Comment: { "examenesConsult": [{ "_id": "64e6709d7abefd92815d1ee1",
            "nombreExamen": "orina",
            "precio": "222",
            "referenciaUno": "wwwwwwwwwwwww",
            "createdAt": "2023-08-23T20:48:29.890Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-08-23T20:48:29.890Z",
            "__v": 0
        }

Comment: amigo este es el objeto de la base de datos

Comment: es excelente si me puedes dar un ejemplo por que asi seria mas especifica la respuesta por fa =)

Comment: Será quizas que te está interpretando esa fecha como un string y no como una fecha de mongo? (la solucion depende de que es lo que estes usando para consultar)